# Why is my basic stack code in java not running?

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

So I´m trying to code the basics of a stack data structure and when I run the class in sample_stack it´s simply not running and not printing the words and instead just printing "null" :( does anyone know why? apologies if this is obvious

STACK JAVA CLASS:

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
public class Stack {

// private inner class node

private class Node{
    
    private String item;
    private Node link;
    
    public Node() {
        item = null;
        link = null;
    }
    
    public Node(String item, Node link) {
        item = this.item;
        link = this.link;
    }
    
}  // end of inner class 

private Node head;

public Stack() {
    head = null;
}

// method: PUSH into stack          (like addToStart)

public void push(String itemName) {
    head = new Node(itemName, head);            // so head is the top of the stack ????
}

// method: POP out of stack

public String pop() {
    if (head == null) throw new IllegalStateException();
    
    else {
        String returnItem = head.item;
        head = head.link;   // the second top item becomes the new head
        return returnItem;
    }
}

// method: is it empty?

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return ( head == null );
}
}
```

CLASS USING THE STACK JAVA CLASS:

```
public class Stack_Example {

public static void main (String[] args) {
    
    Stack message = new Stack();
    
    message.push("Hi");
    
    System.out.println(message.pop());
    
    message.push("my");
    message.push("name");
    message.push("is");
    message.push("JARVIS");
    
    
    while (!message.isEmpty()) {            // while true
        String s = message.pop();
        System.out.println(s);
    }           
}
    
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void push(String itemName) {
    head = new Node(itemName, head);            // so head is the top of the stack ????
}
```

head is null when you call the constructor, and so the link here, `public Node(String item, Node link) {` is always null

Don't you want,

```
public void push(String itemName) {
    head = new Node(itemName, this);
}
```

instead?

Also, this is backwards:

```
public Node(String item, Node link) {
    item = this.item;
    link = this.link;
}
```

It should be:

```
public Node(String item, Node link) {
    this.item = item;
    this.link = link;
}
```

More importantly, you should be debugging all of this as you go along